# Need flex textarea to wrap mid-words

Tags: apache-flex, textarea

I have a textarea with some long names in it (50+ characters).

I set the textAlign property to 'justify', and it wrap every thing well, except for those very long names.

This is how I define my textArea

```
<s:TextArea 
    id="textField"
    textAlign="justify"
    editable="false"
    styleName="ReadOnly"
    width="100%"
    height="100%"
    verticalScrollPolicy="auto"/>
```

I have something like (unwrapped):

```
Name: BAL-BLALBLALBL:ABLABLL:BALBALBLABLALBLBLB:LALB
```

What I expect to see it

```
Name: BAL-BLALBLALB
L:ABLABLL:BALBALBLA
BLALBLBLB:LALB
```

What I get instead is (with the extra spaces between Name and the beginning of the name):

```
Name:          BAL-
BLALBLALBL:ABLABLL:
BALBALBLABLALBLBLB:
LALB
```

It is those extra spaces that really annoy me.

But I remember seeing something somewhere about being able to cut the text mid-word instead of at the blank space or special characters

And I do not want to have to check for the size of the name and split it myself.

I am OK with changing the TextArea to something else as long as the new control support text selection (but not editing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `breakOpportunity="none"` in the `TextArea`. For example:

```
<s:TextArea 
     id="textField"
     textAlign="justify"
     editable="false"
     styleName="ReadOnly"
     width="100%"
     height="100%"
     verticalScrollPolicy="auto"
     breakOpportunity="none"/>
```